# javascript onclick scroll to div on middle page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

javascript onclick scroll to div on middle page ?

I tested my code, but not scroll to middle page,

How to scroll to middle of page ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ytgu1fbo/2/

```
<script>
function scroll_to_contact_form_fn() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myForm").offset().top -500
    }, 200);
}
</script>
```

i Tried this code too but not scroll ^^

```
<script>
function scroll_to_contact_form_fn() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myForm").offset().middle
    }, 200);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like it's working for me. Is your problem that it's scrolling to the wrong spot, or that it's not scrolling at all? If it's not scrolling at all, what browser are you using?

Comment: just remove the  -500.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/ytgu1fbo/7/

Basically first you calculate the total scroll height. Then you go to the middle of the page and then up for the half of your visible area.

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: height/2 - window.innerHeight/2
}, 200);
```

I hope that I understood what you wanted to do correctly